How to sign HTTP Response and put it into header?
I use FastEndpoints over ASP.NET Core minimal API and want to sign the response body which is in application/json format.
I think instead of calling SendAsync(MyResponse) I need to:

serialize MyResponse to JSON,
get signature of the JSON text,
add it to the Response.Header
and then send the JSON in the body.

I'd like to use the same JSON serializer with exactly the same options as if I call SendAsync(MyResponse). And I don't know how to access the serializer from endpoint.
What I tried to do:

I saw the answer how to replace Body.Stream at the middleware but I don't think it's a good idea. In addition I need to sign only specific endpoints.

I tried to use IPostProcessor but I can't read from response Body.

I tried to use IResponseInterceptor but it seems to just add


I use custom json options like this:
var app = bld.Build();
app
    .UseAuthentication()
    .UseAuthorization()
    .UseFastEndpoints(c =>
    {
        c.Endpoints.RoutePrefix = "api/v1";
        c.Serializer.Options.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter(JsonNamingPolicy.SnakeCaseUpper));
    })
    .UseSwaggerGen()
    ;


a custom send extension method should get the job done nicely. something like the following:
var bld = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
bld.Services
   .Configure<JsonOptions>(o => o.SerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null)
   .AddFastEndpoints()
   .SwaggerDocument();

var app = bld.Build();
app.UseFastEndpoints()
   .UseSwaggerGen();
app.Run();

sealed class MyResponse
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

sealed class MyEndpoint : Ep.NoReq.Res<MyResponse>
{
    public override void Configure()
    {
        Get("test");
        AllowAnonymous();
    }

    public override async Task HandleAsync(CancellationToken c)
    {
        await this.SendSignedResponse(new MyResponse { Name = "test" });
    }
}

static class SendExtensions
{
    public static Task SendSignedResponse<TResponse>(this IEndpoint ep, TResponse dto)
    {
        var jsonOptions = ep.HttpContext.Resolve<IOptions<JsonOptions>>().Value.SerializerOptions;
        var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(dto, jsonOptions);
        var md5 = BitConverter.ToString(MD5.HashData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json))).Replace("-", "").ToLower();

        ep.HttpContext.MarkResponseStart();
        ep.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Append("x-signature", md5);

        return ep.HttpContext.Response.SendStringAsync(json);
    }
}


It is quite close to what I want to but it doesn't take into account real json options.
The string var jsonOptions = ep.HttpContext.Resolve<IOptions<JsonOptions>>().Value.SerializerOptions; didn't compile and I changed it like var jsonOptions = HttpContext.Resolve<IOptions<JsonOptions>>()?.Value.JsonSerializerOptions; . Maybe the problem is here....

var config = HttpContext.Resolve<Config>();var jsonOptions = config.Serializer.Options;  works

If you fix your solution according the comment above I will approve your answer

code above compiles and runs just fine.

Yes, but it doesn't solve my problem

as long as you register your own json options like builder.Services .Configure<JsonOptions>(...) during app startup, you will get the exact same json options when you do .Resolve<IOptions<JsonOptions>>().Value.SerializerOptions. i tested the above code in a fresh project before posting and it works fine. something else might be going on if it's not working for you. please provide a minimalistic repro project either via gh issues or discord server if you need further help.

My goal is to keep one place to configure json options. And as far as I want to sign up only selected endpoint I want to have common place for configuring. It has to be in the UseFastEndpoints call. I don't want to duplicate json options and forget to update one of them (as would in your solution). That's why I get json options from Config as I provided in the comments. Don't worry, I can answer on my question on my own if you againts to adjust your answer.

there is absolutely no need to duplicate the json settings. as mentioned in the docs:  When using the options pattern, there's no need to specify it again inside the UseFastEndpoints(...) call and the library will use the same settings from the JsonOptions. so... you can just move all your json settings to the builder.Services .Configure<JsonOptions>(...) call.
